# Still permitted vs. It is still permitted

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-choice

Which one of these sentences is correct?

- It is still permitted, though violates the idea behind the Continuation Lines section.
- It is still permitted, though it violates the idea behind the Continuation Lines section.
- Still permitted, though it violates the idea behind the Continuation Lines section.

In my native language, the best option is the 3rd one, but I'm not sure whether it is correct in English.

The 2nd option looks OK to me from the grammatical side, but is somewhat cumbersome, isn't it?

Comment: The problem with the third option is that the primary clause ("Still permitted") lacks a subject and a verb, so it is not a proper sentence. It's fine in casual speech, but not in formal writing.

Comment: The third one looks like a note rather than a proper sentence; for example, there might be a list of actions with notes to say whether each one is legally permitted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#2) looks the most natural.  However, as the independent clause is followed by the dependent clause, the comma should be deleted.

#1) without the subject after the 'though', one way to improve it is to have its 'violate' changed to 'violating'.  Similar to 2), the comma is deleted.

#3) looks unnatural.  Shifting 'though' to the beginning of the sentence will improve it, but will give it a slight negative feel.

My suggestions are:
#1) It is still permitted though 'violating' the idea behind the Continuation Lines section.

#2) It is still permitted though it violates the idea behind the Continuation Lines section.

#3) Though still permitted, it violates the idea behind the Continuation Lines section.